# Login/Register Spring Security + JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[image]

*I have a problem when I try to register in spring security from the postman and it keeps giving me this error:*

```
"timeStamp": "03-25-2021 07:21:15",
"httpStatusCode": 500,
"httpStatus": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
"reason": "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR",
"message": "An error occurred while processing the request"
```

*the code for this problem as you can see below I searched a lot but no answer at all about it so I put it here:

*this is the Service Code I called it (UserImplService)*

```
 public User register(String firstName, String lastName, String username, String email)
        throws UserNotFoundException, UsernameExistException, EmailExistException {
    validateNewUsernameAndEmail(EMPTY, username, email);
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserId(generateUserId());
    String password = generatePassword();
    user.setFirstName(firstName);
    user.setLastName(lastName);
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setJoinDate(new Date());
    user.setPassword(encodePassword(password));
    user.setActive(true);
    user.setNotLocked(true);
    user.setRole(ROLE_USER_AUTHORITIES.name());
    user.setAuthorities(ROLE_USER_AUTHORITIES.getAuthorities());
    user.setProfileImageUrl(getTemporaryProfileImageUrl(username));`enter code `
    userRepository.insert(user);
    LOGGER.info("New user password: " + password);
```

*and this is the Controller for this service as you can see it:*

*even when I run the debug mode it didn’t give me a clear explanation about the bug.*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = { "/user"}) 
public class UserController extends ExceptionHandling {
private UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  public UserController(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}


@PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestBody User user) throws UserNotFoundException, UsernameExistException, EmailExistException {
        User newUser = userService.register(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getUsername(), user.getEmail());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newUser, OK);
    }
```

}

Comment: You need to provide us exception stack trace from the server. 500 error is too generic and it is telling that something went wrong on the server.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean sir  @SpasojePetronijević

Comment: He meant the logs from the server, especially the ones that come after you send the request from postman

Comment: it's all clear I think @aksappy

Comment: Can you take a look at your console? Maybe you can see some exception there. 500 can mean NullPointerException, IndexOutOfBoundsException and many others.